# Constructing DataFrame from Dict with numeric keys in Julia

Tags: julia, dataframes.jl

I would like to construct a `DataFrames.jl` data frame from a Julia `Dict` with integer numeric columns. I feel like this should be as simple as:

```
using DataFrames

mydict = Dict(1 => 1, 2 => 2)
mydf = DataFrame(mydict)
```

But this does not work because in this case, `DataFrame` expects a `Dict` with keys of type `Symbol` or `string`. What would be a concise way to construct a `DataFrame` from a `Dict` with non `Symbol` or `string` keys?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are two examples how to do it:

```
julia> DataFrame(Symbol.(keys(mydict)) .=> values(mydict))
1×2 DataFrame
 Row │ 2      1
     │ Int64  Int64
─────┼──────────────
   1 │     2      1

julia> DataFrame(Symbol(k) => v for (k, v) in pairs(mydict))
2×2 DataFrame
 Row │ first   second
     │ Symbol  Int64
─────┼────────────────
   1 │ 2            2
   2 │ 1            1
```

The reason why we only accept strings or `Symbol` values as column names is that, in general, even if two keys would be considered different in source dictionary they might have a string representation, causing ambiguity.

For this reason and user safety both DataFrames.jl and Tables.jl assume that column names cannot be arbitrary values.

Comment: I will edit the question so that it is less ambiguous and corresponds to your answer. I think this will be a useful little Q&A. However, I am wondering how come why a method like this is not already implemented in the DataFrame constructor.

Comment: I have added a comment why we disallow this.